# Spark avoiding small partitions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a users "table" which I want to partition by "location". However when trying to use:

```
usersNewDf.write.partitionBy("location") \
    .parquet("....../parquet/users.parquet")
```

I get alot of "attempt*" files, I think I saw somewhere it might be because I have too many small partitions? Which when checking seems true. Many locations have only 1 user. So I am thinking for those users I will clear the location.

I am wondering, is this the best way? Isit possible to partition by location without clearing uncommon locations? Like maybe if the partition is too small, group them up?

If I were to clear uncommon locations, I may have large number of users without a location, so 1 big partition. Is this ok? Or what can I do to improve the situation?

---

Also should I be using `partitionBy` or `repartition` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should repartition("location") before you write.partitionBy("location") otherwise multiple working partitions (after a shuffle of the data) will write to the same file partition

Comment: Oh is that why I am getting a ton of small files? https://imgur.com/a/zStck https://imgur.com/TxYdid9

Comment: yup - same location can be scattered all over the cluster and each writer creates its own "part" files - if you repartition first you'd only get one